# C# MVC: Do you have to rebuild when you update the route config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, routes

Using C# MVC, I notice the route config updates don't take affect. Do I have to rebuild every time I update the route config to see the changes on my local?

The next extreme would be deleting the `bin` directory, but I'm hoping I don't have to do that every time.

Comment: Yes, because the RouteConfig is built into the assembly.

Comment: @Jon so a plain build won't work?

Comment: Yeah just stopping Debug and then F5 to build again and run should work? This isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

RouteConfig is a c# class , it is built into your assembly and after every change you need to rebuild your solution. 
If you want to update your route config without rebuilding application , make your config into the web config file as application params then read the param from your routeConfig class